# create JPanel after click the button /Java

Tags: java, jpanel

I have a problem with my project. I would like to create new Panel in my Frame after click the button. Here's a part of a code:

```
private class ComponentListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(newGameItem)) 
        {
            System.out.println("dasda");
            gamePanel = new GamePanel();
            cont.add(gamePanel);

        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(stopItem)) {
            gamePanel.stopGame();
        }
    }
}

GamePanel gamePanel;

Container cont = this.getContentPane();
```

When I click the button I see the text in console, also when I'm starting project already with this Panel everything is okay.
I guess this problem is simple but I can't figure out what's going on :( .

---

I see "dasda" so it means that method actionPerformed works correctly.
miniwolf where should I invoke repaint? In actionPerformed?

Comment: Post all of your code.

Comment: what text are you seeing in the console?

Comment: Maybe you need to call repaint()?

Comment: @miniwolf that could be it since it's a panel

Comment: stop guessing. If you want real help then post your real full code. where do you create your button? do you add the action listener to it? Edit your question so we can help you.

Comment: No! `System.out.println();` will work anywhere when other stuff may have issues.

Comment: Have you tried calling invalidate() on the parent container of the panel? I would suggest calling either repaint or invalidate after the line where you add it to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution. I should have added `gamePanel.revalidate()` in `actionPerformed`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have to refresh this topic, cause I have a problem with change JPanel in JFrame form.
When I click the button I want to change a panel but I can't see it, but when I create JFrame (java class) and write code by myself everything's okay.

This is a code from JFrame (java class) made by me.

```
 public class main extends JFrame
{
    public main()
    {
        frameSettings();
        this.getContentPane().add(panel1);
        panel1.add(button);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            gamePanel = new GamePanel();
            container.add(gamePanel);
            gamePanel.startGame();
            gamePanel.revalidate();
            gamePanel.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
private void frameSettings() {
    int szer = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    int wys = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    this.setTitle("Pong");
    this.setSize(700, 600);
    this.setResizable(false);
    int szerRamki = this.getSize().width;
    int wysRamki = this.getSize().height;
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    this.setLocation((szer - szerRamki) / 2, (wys - wysRamki) / 2);

}
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton();
GamePanel gamePanel;
Container container = this.getContentPane();
public static void main(String args[])
{

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new main().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And this is a code from JFrame form

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

/**
 * Creates new form MainFrame
 */
public MainFrame()
{

    initComponents();
    frameSettings();

}

private void frameSettings()
{
    int szer = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    int wys = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    this.setTitle("Pong");
    this.setSize(700, 600);
    this.setResizable(false);
    int szerRamki = this.getSize().width;
    int wysRamki = this.getSize().height;
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    this.setLocation((szer - szerRamki) / 2, (wys - wysRamki) / 2);

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents()
{

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 3, 160)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 255));
    jLabel1.setText("Pong");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 3, 48)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 0));
    jLabel2.setText("Nowa Gra");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 3, 48)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 0));
    jLabel3.setText("Ranking");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 3, 48)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 0));
    jLabel4.setText("Wyjście");

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 0));
    jLabel5.setText("Najlepszy gracz:");

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(237, 237, 237)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 302, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(227, 227, 227)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(148, 148, 148)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 131, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(102, 102, 102))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(57, 57, 57)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel5))
    );

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    jMenuItem1.setText("Nowa Gra");
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuItem2.setText("jMenuItem2");
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuItem3.setText("jMenuItem3");
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Edit");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                         
{                                             
    System.out.println("askdalk");
            gamePanel = new GamePanel();
            container.add(gamePanel);
            gamePanel.startGame();
            gamePanel.revalidate();
            gamePanel.requestFocus();
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[])
{
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try
    {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
        {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
            {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private Container container = this.getContentPane();
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
private GamePanel gamePanel;
```

}